# No ".includes?" ruby method when running RSpec Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I've recently got into RSpec and i'm writing some tests for my code, one of things my code has is a section where it starts by going `if category.name.includes?(matcher)` and then it does something, running this code in production is fine however whenever i'm testing that piece of code with RSpec I get the following error:

`undefined method 'includes?' for "category21":String`

To clear some things up, my factories do clearly define the categories name, i'm mainly wondering if I need to include some form of library to get it to play nicely?

Thanks, Grant

Comment: I wonder if it's some  "refinements" at play... (or possibly a library being included in production that hasn't been included in your test)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [include?](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/include%3F), not `includes?`.

Comment: You're absolutely right, that's the most stupid mistake i've made all day, thanks :)

Comment: @grant -- if it helps you any, I make this same mistake so often I'm starting to consider monkey-patching `Enumerable`...